# How to write this piece of code in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I want to implement this javascript code in jquery, please!

```
    var html = '';

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*39)+1;
            html += num + ' ';
        }
        html += '<br>';
    }

    document.getElementById('rows').innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: Whats wrong with above code? Apart from `$('#rows').html(html)` in place of `document.getElementById('rows').innerHTML = html;`. Rest is fine

Comment: replace `document.getElementById('rows').innerHTML = html;` with `$('#rows').html(html);`

Comment: That code is perfectly valid jQuery, given that jQuery itself is just JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted and there is not much difference between the straight javascript version and a version written in jQuery. The only different is the last line, where you select the `rows` object. In jQuery you get the object using `$('#rows')`.

Here you go:

```
var html = '';

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*39)+1;
            html += num + ' ';
        }
        html += '<br>';
    }

    $('#rows').html(html);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am a new coder, so, I am so lost sometimes!!

Comment: No problem, you'll pick it up quickly. If this solved your problem, make sure to tick it as your chosen answer!